# Simulate Background Gamma Radiation for Localization

Tags: measurements, simulations, gamma-rays, noise

I'm working on a gamma radiation source localization project. The gamma radiation measurement model is:

$\lambda_k =  \frac{I}{(x_s - x_k)^2 + (y_s - x_y)^2} +\lambda_b$.

Where $\lambda_k$ is the $k^{th}$ counts measurement, $I$ is the gamma source intensity,$(x_s,y_s)$ are the gamma source location,$(x_k,y_k)$ are the $k^{th}$ detector coordinates and $\lambda_b$ is the background radiation. The measurement time is constant for all measurements.

I want to add background gamma radiation for an unobstructed, homogeneous environment. Below is an example of a simulated detector path and counts measurement.

I imagine the best case would be to actually measure the background gamma radiation in the experimental environment and then use it in conjunction with the source simulation data. So if the best case is not available, are there any experimentally valid methods to achieve a simulated background gamma radiation that is representative for specific environments?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The graph you've drawn dosen't represent a sampling of Poisson distribution but an analytic curve. You should probably start by drawing from the representative distribution.

Comment: indeed thank you, I've updated the plot to represent sampling from a Poisson distribution

Comment: What does the graph represent? Why is there a time axis? What defines $t=0$? Why does the graph rise and fall? *What is an experimentally valid method to achieve a representative background gamma radiation for a variety of signal to noise ratios?* It's not very clear to me what you're asking here. What does "representative" mean in this context?

Comment: Let me second @Ben's comment here. And let me try to help you out with this as you may be suffering from assumed context (not realizing that your audience isn't as familiar with the problem as you are because you've been staring at it for a while). Just from the description of the problem I assume there is an implicit motion in space as the detector is carried around: that you started near the source, jgt closer until around 15 seconds into the test, then farther away. But you haven't *said* that.

Comment: Yes I was definitely assuming context... I've updated the question (I'm sure I've missed details)

Comment: Are you measuring an energy spectrum (as with a NaI or Ge detector), or only a count rate (as with a Geiger counter)? What aspect of the background do you need a model for? Its energy spectrum?

Comment: For now, count rate. In regards to the second question, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing a simulation you decide what to put into it.

If you want it to be a *useful* simulation, you generally take guidance on those decisions for what you think the real situation is.

Simulating a background is no different from simulating a signal: you decide what you think the characteristics of the background are and code them up.

In this case I would be looking at two possible background:

1. Ambient sources (cosmics and radon probably)
2. Localized backgrounds (poatsium-40 in the walls; local low level contamination of sites in the facility distinct from the source you are trying to localize, etc.)

Ambient sourrces can be expected to be constant on the kinds of time-scales you are looking at and the same everywhere in space. Draw from another Poisson distribution with a constant mean.

Localized sources are treated similarly to your target signal. More draws. More addition.

If your detector system has non-trivial energy resolution, you need to be modeling that as well, but if you have a pure counting detector (Geiger detector...) you are well on your way.

---

*Aside:* Are you simulating detector dead time? Should you be?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. In general, the simulation should incorporate detector dead time for high activity gamma sources or when the detector path is close to the source?

Comment: You incorporate dead-time (or any other effect) when leaving it out would impact the fidelity of the model at an unacceptable level. (Well, if you are smart your start incorporating it when you can see that case coming...) That is, if you need five percent precision in your model and the dead time would be several percent you start getting itchy about not having it. Which puts you in the usual circular place of needing to know the answer to a question (here "what is the dead time?") to decide if you need to answer that same question.